# Timeout for function in the kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, timeout

I'm trying to add a timeout for a c function in the kernel.

I'd like to do something like the function `try_until_timeout` of the following pseudocode:

```c
void myfunction() {/* [...] */}

void myfunction_cleanup() {/* [...] */}

int main( void ) {
    boolean hasFinished = try_until_timeout(myfunction, HZ/10 ) // The task has 100 ms of processor time to complete
    if(!hasFinished) { // if the task have timeouted
        hasFinished = try_until_timeout(myfunction_cleanup, HZ/10 ) // The task has 100 ms of processor time to come back to a clean state
        if(!hasFinished) { // if the cleanup also timeouted
            printk(KERN_WARN "Task and cleanup failed to finish in time. Aborting.");
            my_kill()
        }
    }    
}
```

In some ways my need is somewhat similar to `pthread_timedjoin_np` except that I'd like to avoid the creation of a new thread for performance reasons.

But I don't know how to do that *cleanly* in the kernel. I think it might be possible by adding a timer_list before the call of the function and deleting it after. In case the timeout is reached, it might be possible to modify the value of the next instruction `$eip` but that approach is extremely dirty, overkill and non-portable thus I'd like to find a cleaner solution to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

You have specific functions on the kernel to manage timers, and in your case the timeouts you should check the functions mod_timer, setup_timer and del_timer.